# How to check if user's current location is inside a location circle

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

i want to check if user if inside a vicinity. For example i have specified a radius of 50 meters around current of location of user. Let's say if user is moving, now i want to check if user in inside 50 meter radius or not. Here is my code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

          locationManager.startMonitoringVisits()
          locationManager.delegate = self
          locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
          locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
          locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() 
    }
```

Here is code for checking distance

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.first else {
            return
        }
        let officeLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 31.471303736482234, longitude: 74.27275174139386)

        let circle = MKCircle(center: officeLocation, radius: 50 as CLLocationDistance)
        if location.distance(from: officeLocation) > circle.radius {
            self.newVisitReceived(des: "YOU ARE OUT OF OFFICE")
        }
        else{ 
            self.newVisitReceived(des: "YOU ARE IN OFFICE")
         }

    }
```

Even if i don't move this code sends notification "YOU ARE OUT".

Comment: There could be any number of things causing this problem. You could be working with a simulator whose location is being hard-coded to one of several different locations all of which are outside your radius. You could be running on a device that hasn't yet received a GPS or AGPS location update and thus your app doesn't know (yet) that it has been moved out of its location.

Comment: So you mean this code is fine?

Comment: Your code seems fine as-is, however I think you might be making some assumptions about the source of the device (or simulator)'s location data.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for my use case.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 5):

I would solve this with Geofences...
You have to specify a coordinate center & radius where you want to listen to the user when he goes inside/outside from your geofence.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {

        // CLLocationCoordinate2D; You have to put the coordinate that you want to listen
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 324234, longitude: 23423), radius: 50, identifier: "Ur ID")
        region.notifyOnExit = true
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        manager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    // User has exited from ur regiom
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    // User has exited from ur region
}
```

I hope this will be useful

Answer (score 0):

The general problem with location services is that the measurements vary in accuracy, depending on a lot of factors. How would your like your code to behave if the user is standing right on the 50 meter boundary? Your current code would then flip back and forth randomly between 'in office' and 'out of office', if the accuracy is bad.

I think accuracy of a GPS is actually more than 4 meters under the best conditions, so a distanceFilter of 1 might not be appropriate.

I guess you would need some state in your app that tracks *when* the user was last seen inside the 50 meter radius, and also some grace period before updating that variable again, to avoid 'flickering'.